# phalcon and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, phalcon

I am using Phalcon PHP framework. First I have problem to get value of Tag::textField in jquery. I am interested in accessing a value of `Tag::textField` from jquery.
Second question is how to call a controller's method using AJAX. I am trying to call method `posalji()` from my XML controller on a button click, and it's not warking. Here is my controller method I am trying to call:

```
public function posaljiAction()
{
    $data = "Ja se zovem Nedim Omerbegovic";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And here is my view (pretraga.phtml):

```
<?php
    use Phalcon\Tag;
?>
<?php
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false);
    echo Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jquery.js");
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dugme").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo $this->url->get("xml/posalji") ?>",
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });     
            });
        });
    </script>

    <h2>Primjer penosa varijable iz controllera to view-a</h2>
    <?php echo Tag::form("xml/pretraga"); ?>
    <p>
        <label for="name">Naslov</label>
        <?php echo Tag::textField("naslov") ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo Tag::submitButton("prikazi") ?>
    </p>
</form>


<form>
    <label for="text">Unesi:</label>
    <p>
        <input type="text" id="unos"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="dugme" value="Prikazi"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you navigate to `/xml/posalji` you will see that the whole layout with your echoed string appears. You will need to disable the view for that particular action:

```
public function posaljiAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();

    $data = "Ja se zovem Nedim Omerbegovic";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

If you want to access any control that is displayed on the view via jQuery, all you need to know is its `id`. So if you pass in the `Tag::textField()` parameters like these:

```
$options = array(
    'some_field_name',
    'id'    => 'some_id',
    'class' => 'some_class',
    'size'  => '10',
);

echo Tag::textField($options);
```

you can then access its value from jQuery like this

```
$('some_id').val()
```

References:

[jQuery val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[Phalcon Tag Helpers](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#using-tag-helpers)

Comment: Is it possible to block a request to this `Action` that is not a `XML Http Request` so that no user could access it directly with their browser ?

Comment: You can add server directives for that area of the site to be accessed only by a particular rage of IPs. You could also add authentication at the top of this action which will send data back to the caller if a user has been logged in etc.

Answer (score 0):

read this pages and use structures:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/request.html

AND

http://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/views.html